# An implementation of a static any type

Tags: c++, c++14, variant-type

This describes type `util::any<std::size_t size, std::size_t align>` - an implementation of `std::any` with a static size/no dynamic allocation. It closely follows the standard's specification for `std::any`.

> A discriminated type that can contain values of different types but
>   does not attempt conversion between them, i.e. 5 is held strictly as
>   an int and is not implicitly convertible either to "5" or to 5.0. This
>   indifference to interpretation but awareness of type effectively
>   allows safe, generic containers of single values, with no scope for
>   surprises from ambiguous conversions.

[Taken from the standard's description of `std::any`]

#### Review goals

- Correctness: The lifetime of objects is managed manually. Are there any invalid states in my code? Can invalid states be generated through usage?
- Optimization: There is a small size overhead required in order to enable type-erasure. Is there a way to make this code faster or require less memory without decreasing performance?
- Design: Any design suggestions/comments are welcome. Most constraints are done through `static_assert`, this generates an informative error message, but does not highlight the actual error location; would it be better to simply remove functions through `std::enable_if`?

#### Usage

Instances of `util::any<std::size_t, std::size_t>` can hold any type that fits in the specified amount of static memory it has been created with. Access of the contained value is done through the `static_any_cast<T>` free functions.

**Example**

```
#include <cassert>
#include "static_any.h"

int main()
{
    util::static_any<4, 4> aa; // holds any type with a size <= 4, aligned as 4
    assert( aa.empty() );

    aa = 'A'; // holds a char
    aa = "abc"; // now holds char const[4];
    //aa = "abcd"; // error: char const[5] is too big.

    aa = 3.0f; // now holds a float
    try
    {
        util::static_any_cast<int>( aa ); // invalid cast; aa holds a float
    }
    catch ( util::bad_static_any_cast const& )
    {}
    assert( util::static_any_cast<float const&>( aa ) == 3.0f ); // view through const-ref

    util::static_any_cast<float&>( aa ) = 5.0f; // modify through reference cast
    assert( util::static_any_cast<float>( aa ) == 5.0f );
}
```

#### Implementation

All relevant parts of the code are commented. This is all in one file, but I've separated into sections for ease of review.

```
#ifndef UTIL_STATIC_ANY_H
#define UTIL_STATIC_ANY_H

#include <new>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>
```

**Implementation - class bad_static_any_cast**

```
namespace util
{
    class bad_static_any_cast : public std::bad_cast
    {
        virtual char const* what() const noexcept override
        {
            return "bad_static_any_cast: casting to invalid type";
        }
    };
}
```

**Implementation - class static_any**

```
namespace util
{
    template <std::size_t size, std::size_t align = 8>
    class static_any;

    template <class StaticAny>
    struct is_static_any : std::false_type {};

    template <std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
    struct is_static_any<static_any<size, align>> : std::true_type {};

    template <std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
    class static_any
    {
    public:
        // [ destructor ]
        ~static_any()
        {
            if ( m_has_value )
            {
                storage_base_ptr()->destroy_contained_value();
            }
        }

        // [ constructors ]
        /**
        * effects: constructs an empty static_any.
        * postcondition: *this does not have a contained value.
        */
        static_any() noexcept
            : m_has_value{ false }
        {
        }

        /**
        * effects: constructs a static_any from another static_any by copying its
                   contained value.
        * requirements: the argument static_any must be smaller or equal in size.
        * throws: any exception thrown by the copy constructor of the contained value.
        */
        template <std::size_t other_size, std::size_t other_align>
        static_any( static_any<other_size, other_align> const& other )
            : m_has_value{ other.m_has_value }
        {
            static_assert( other_size <= size,
                "static_any error: cannot be constructed from a larger static_any" );

            if ( m_has_value )
            {
                other.storage_base_ptr()->copy_to( &m_memory );
            }
        }

        /**
        * effects: constructs a static_any from another static_any by moving its
                   contained value.
        * requires: the argument static_any must be smaller or equal in size.
        * throws: any exception thrown by the move constructor of the contained value.
        */
        template <std::size_t other_size, std::size_t other_align>
        static_any( static_any<other_size, other_align>&& other )
            : m_has_value{ other.m_has_value }
        {
            static_assert( other_size <= size,
                "static_any error: cannot be constructed from a larger static_any" );

            if ( m_has_value )
            {
                other.storage_base_ptr()->move_to( &m_memory );
                other.m_has_value = false;
            }
        }

        /**
        * effects: constructs a static_any containing a direct-initialized value of
                   type std::decay_t<T>.
        * requires: type std::decay_t<T> must be copy constructible.
        * throws: any exceptions thrown by the selected constructor of std::decay_t<T>.
        */
        template
        <
            class T,
            std::enable_if_t<!is_static_any<std::decay_t<T>>::value, int> = 0
        >
        static_any( T&& value )
            : m_has_value{ true }
        {
            static_assert( sizeof( T ) <= size,
                "incompatible type size; requires sizeof(T) <= size" );

            static_assert( std::is_copy_constructible<std::decay<T>>::value,
                "std::decay_t<T> must be copy constructible" );

            ::new ( &m_memory ) storage<std::decay_t<T>>( std::forward<T>( value ) );
        }

        // [ assignment ]
        /**
        * effects: static_any{rhs}.swap(*this);
                   no effects if an exception is thrown.
        * requires: the argument static_any must be smaller or equal in size.
        * returns: *this.
        * throws: any exception thrown by the copy constructor of the contained
                  value of the argument static_any.
        */
        template <std::size_t other_size, std::size_t other_align>
        static_any& operator=( static_any<other_size, other_align> const& rhs )
        {
            static_any{ rhs }.swap( *this );
            return *this;
        }

        /**
        * effects: static_any{std::move(rhs)}.swap(*this);
                   no effects if an exception is thrown.
        * requires: the argument static_any must be smaller or equal in size.
        * returns: *this.
        * throws: any exception thrown by the move constructor of the contained
                  value of the argument static_any.
        */
        template <std::size_t other_size, std::size_t other_align>
        static_any& operator=( static_any<other_size, other_align>&& rhs )
        {
            static_any{ std::move( rhs ) }.swap( *this );
            return *this;
        }

        /**
        * effects: static_any{std::forward<T>(rhs)}.swap(*this);
                   no effects if an exception is thrown.
        * requires: type std::decay_t<T> must be copy constructible.
        * returns: *this.
        * throws: any exception thrown by the selected constructor of std::decay_t<T>.
        */
        template
        <
            class T,
            std::enable_if_t<!is_static_any<std::decay_t<T>>::value, int> = 0
        >
        static_any& operator=( T&& value )
        {
            static_any{ std::forward<T>( value ) }.swap( *this );
            return *this;
        }

        // [ modifiers ]
        /**
        * effects: if *this has a contained value, destroy the contained value.
        * postcondition: *this does not have a contained value.
        */
        void clear()
        {
            if ( m_has_value )
            {
                storage_base_ptr()->destroy_contained_value();
                m_has_value = false;
            }
        }

        /**
        * effects: exchanges the contained values of *this and argument other.
        */
        void swap( static_any& other )
        {
            if ( this != &other )
            {
                if ( m_has_value && other.m_has_value )
                {
                    other.unsafe_swap( *this );
                }
                else if ( m_has_value )
                {
                    storage_base* storage_ptr{ storage_base_ptr() };

                    storage_ptr->move_to( &other.m_memory );
                    other.m_has_value = true;

                    storage_ptr->destroy_contained_value();
                    m_has_value = false;
                }
                else if ( other.m_has_value )
                {
                    storage_base* other_storage_ptr{ other.storage_base_ptr() };

                    other_storage_ptr->move_to( &m_memory );
                    m_has_value = true;

                    other_storage_ptr->destroy_contained_value();
                    other.m_has_value = false;
                }
            }
        }

        /**
        * effects: exchanges the contained values of *this and argument other without
                   checking for valid state (non-empty instances, self-assign, etc.).
        */
        template <std::size_t other_size, std::size_t other_align>
        void unsafe_swap( static_any<other_size, other_align>& other )
        {
            memory_t tmp;

            storage_base* storage_ptr{ storage_base_ptr() };
            storage_ptr->move_to( &tmp );
            storage_ptr->destroy_contained_value();

            storage_base* other_storage_ptr{ other.storage_base_ptr() };
            other_storage_ptr->move_to( &m_memory );
            other_storage_ptr->destroy_contained_value();

            reinterpret_cast<storage_base*>( &tmp )->move_to( &other.m_memory );
        }

        // [ observers ]
        /**
        * effects: indicates whether the static_any has a contained value or not.
        * returns: true if *this has no contained value, otherwise false.
        */
        bool empty() const noexcept
        {
            return !m_has_value;
        }

        /**
        * effects: accesses the std::type_info of the associated contained value.
        * returns: typeid(T) if *this has a contained value, otherwise typeid(void).
        */
        std::type_info const& type() const noexcept
        {
            static std::type_info const& void_type_info{ typeid( void ) };
            return m_has_value ? storage_base_ptr()->type() : void_type_info;
        }

    private:
        // [ friend declarations ]
        template <std::size_t other_size, std::size_t other_align>
        friend class static_any;

        template <class T, std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
        friend T static_any_cast( static_any<size, align>& operand );

        template <class T, std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
        friend T static_any_cast( static_any<size, align> const& operand );

        template <class T, std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
        friend T static_any_cast( static_any<size, align>&& operand );

        template <class T, std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
        friend T* static_any_cast( static_any<size, align>* operand ) noexcept;

        template <class T, std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
        friend T const* static_any_cast( static_any<size, align> const* operand ) noexcept;

        // [ helper types ]
        /**
        * base storage class
        */
        class storage_base
        {
        public:
            virtual ~storage_base() = default;

            storage_base( std::type_info const& type_info )
                : m_type_info{ type_info }
            {}

            virtual void copy_to( void* p_location ) const = 0;
            virtual void move_to( void* p_location ) = 0;
            virtual void destroy_contained_value() = 0;

            std::type_info const& type() const noexcept
            {
                return m_type_info;
            }

        private:
            std::type_info const& m_type_info;
        };

        /**
        * helper type used to determine the maximum size of *this' storage<T>
        */
        class storage_size_t : public storage_base
        {
            char filler[ size ];
        };

        /**
        * wrapper type to be created in static uninitialized memory
        * the contained value must be freed with a call to destroy_contained_value()
        */
        template <class T>
        class storage : public storage_base
        {
        public:
            template <class U>
            storage( U&& value )
                noexcept( std::is_nothrow_constructible<T, U&&>::value )
                : storage_base( typeid( T ) )
                , m_value( std::forward<U>( value ) )
            {
            }

            storage( storage const& ) = delete;
            storage( storage&& ) = delete;

            storage& operator=( storage const& ) = delete;
            storage& operator=( storage&& ) = delete;

            void copy_to( void* p_location ) const override
            {
                ::new ( p_location ) storage( m_value );
            }

            void move_to( void* p_location ) override
            {
                ::new ( p_location ) storage( std::move( m_value ) );
            }

            void destroy_contained_value() override
            {
                m_value.~T();
            }

            T m_value;

        private:
            ~storage() = default;
        };

        storage_base* storage_base_ptr()
        {
            return reinterpret_cast<storage_base*>( &m_memory );
        }

        storage_base const* storage_base_ptr() const
        {
            return reinterpret_cast<storage_base const*>( &m_memory );
        }

        using memory_t = std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof( storage_size_t ), align>;
        memory_t m_memory;
        bool m_has_value;
    };
}
```

**Implementation - free functions**

```
namespace util
{
    // [ non-member functions ]
    /**
    * effects: x.swap( y ).
    */
    template <std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
    void swap( static_any<size, align>& x, static_any<size, align>& y ) noexcept
    {
        x.swap( y );
    }

    /**
    * requires: std::is_reference<T>::value && std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value.
    * returns: *static_any_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>>( &operand ).
    * throws: bad_static_any_cast if operand.type() != typeid( std::remove_reference_t<T> ).
    */
    template <class T, std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
    T static_any_cast( static_any<size, align>& operand )
    {
        static_assert(
            std::is_reference<T>::value || std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value,
            "any_cast requirement not met: T is a reference or copy constructible" );

        auto ret{ static_any_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>>( &operand ) };
        if ( ret )
        {
            return *ret;
        }
        throw bad_static_any_cast{};
    }

    /**
    * requires: std::is_reference<T>::value && std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value.
    * returns: *static_any_cast<std::add_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>(&operand).
    * throws: bad_static_any_cast if operand.type() != typeid(std::remove_reference_t<T>).
    */
    template <class T, std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
    T static_any_cast( static_any<size, align> const& operand )
    {
        static_assert(
            std::is_reference<T>::value || std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value,
            "any_cast requirement not met: T is a reference or copy constructible" );

        auto ret
        {
            static_any_cast<std::add_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>( &operand )
        };

        if ( ret )
        {
            return *ret;
        }
        throw bad_static_any_cast{};
    }

    /**
    * requires: std::is_reference<T>::value && std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value.
    * returns: *static_any_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>>(&operand).
    * throws: bad_static_any_cast if operand.type() != typeid(std::remove_reference_t<T>).
    */
    template <class T, std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
    T static_any_cast( static_any<size, align>&& operand )
    {
        static_assert(
            std::is_reference<T>::value || std::is_copy_constructible<T>::value,
            "any_cast requirement not met: T is a reference or copy constructible" );

        auto ret{ static_any_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>>( &operand ) };
        if ( ret )
        {
            return *ret;
        }
        throw bad_static_any_cast{};
    }

    /**
    * returns: if operand != nullptr && operand->type() == typeid(T),
               a pointer to the object contained by operand, otherwise nullptr.
    */
    template <class T, std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
    T* static_any_cast( static_any<size, align>* operand ) noexcept
    {
        static std::type_info const& typeid_value = typeid( std::remove_reference_t<T> );

        using pointer = static_any<size, align>::template storage<T>*;

        return operand && operand->type() == typeid_value ?
            &static_cast<pointer>( operand->storage_base_ptr() )->m_value : nullptr;
    }

    /**
    * returns: if operand != nullptr && operand->type() == typeid(T),
               a pointer to const of the object contained by operand, otherwise nullptr.
    */
    template <class T, std::size_t size, std::size_t align>
    T const* static_any_cast( static_any<size, align> const* operand ) noexcept
    {
        static std::type_info const& typeid_value = typeid( std::remove_reference_t<T> );

        using pointer = static_any<size, align>::template storage<T> const*;

        return operand && operand->type() == typeid_value ?
            &static_cast<pointer>( operand->storage_base_ptr() )->m_value : nullptr;
    }
}
#endif // UTIL_STATIC_ANY_H
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a thorough review, but I'll mention a few interesting points...

---

Your `static_any` is part of a noble tradition of in-place type-erased types. See also

- Carl Cook's [`stdext::inplace_function<R(A...), Cap, Align>`](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/SG14/blob/master/SG14/inplace_function.h)
- Tiemo Jung's [`tj::inplace_any<Cap, Align>`](https://github.com/TieJu/inplace_any/blob/master/inplace_any.h)
- David Grs' [`static_any<Cap>` and `static_any_t<Cap>`](https://github.com/david-grs/static_any) (the latter, a horrible misuse of the suffix-`_t` convention, is specialized to hold nothing but trivially copyable types)

Reading the code of these libraries will give you a lot of ideas for how to optimize the representation; for example, how to get rid of `m_has_value`. It may also help with the "SFINAE versus `static_assert`" question, which I don't address in this review but I agree that it's a good question to think about.

---

Your `unsafe_swap` function has a bug. Here's the code again:

```
    template <std::size_t other_size, std::size_t other_align>
    void unsafe_swap( static_any<other_size, other_align>& other )
    {
        memory_t tmp;

        storage_base* storage_ptr{ storage_base_ptr() };
        storage_ptr->move_to( &tmp );
        storage_ptr->destroy_contained_value();

        storage_base* other_storage_ptr{ other.storage_base_ptr() };
        other_storage_ptr->move_to( &m_memory );
        other_storage_ptr->destroy_contained_value();

        reinterpret_cast<storage_base*>( &tmp )->move_to( &other.m_memory );
    }
```

Notice that the calls to `move_to` and `destroy_contained_value` always come in pairs: first we do both on `storage_ptr`, then we do both on `other_storage_ptr`, then we do both on... oops! Red flag! We have forgotten to destroy the `T` object that was move-constructed into the memory of `tmp` on the first line. The missing destructor call could produce a memory leak, resource leak, or worse.

In an ideal world, the red flag of "[faulty parallel construction](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/5-examples-of-faulty-parallel-structure/)" would have tipped you off to this bug. But I admit that I was particularly *looking* for this kind of bug because I'd already seen it happen in the wild, [in the code of `stdext::inplace_function`](https://github.com/WG21-SG14/SG14/pull/117). Type-erased move and swap are theoretically no harder than any other type-erased operation; yet empirical experience has shown me that in reality *nobody gets them right* on the first try.

---

As you might have guessed from that pull request, and from the observation that move and destroy *must* appear in pairs, IMHO it is good practice to combine them into a single operation, whose [widely accepted name](https://github.com/electronicarts/EASTL/blob/master/include/EASTL/type_traits.h#L34-L37) is `relocate`. However, you'll still need a type-erased `destroy` operation as well, to call in your actual destructor.

---

```
static std::type_info const& void_type_info{ typeid( void ) };
return m_has_value ? storage_base_ptr()->type() : void_type_info;
```

The above is so much more needlessly verbose than

```
return m_has_value ? storage_base_ptr()->type() : typeid(void);
```

Prefer the shorter version. (This applies to several places in your code.)

---

On the other hand, in one of your `any_cast` functions, you write:

```
auto ret{
    static_any_cast<std::add_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>( &operand )
};
if (ret) {
    return *ret;
}
throw bad_static_any_cast{};
```

(I've already taken the liberty of normalizing your indentation style. My editor window's vertical space is valuable; don't waste it!) Here, I think you've put the verbosity in the wrong place. I would have *pulled out* that confusing and ultimately "skim-over-able" type into a typedef, and *collapsed* all the value-space logic into a single line.

```
using U = std::add_const_t<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
auto ret = static_any_cast<U>(&operand);
return ret ? *ret : throw bad_static_any_cast();
```

My vendetta against curly braces is purely personal preference; I wouldn't say you were wrong if you preferred `auto ret{static_any_cast...}` and `throw bad_static_any_cast{}`. I tend to use curlies only for code blocks and aggregate initializers; for things that are "intuitively" settings-equal or function-invocations, I personally prefer `=` or `()` respectively.

---

Speaking of `static_any_cast` and `bad_static_any_cast`: Do you think it's a good feature that these are spelled differently from the existing `any_cast` and `bad_any_cast`?  I would naturally expect them to use the existing names, so that I could write

```
#ifdef FASTER
using any = util::static_any<32>;
#else
using any = std::any;
#endif
template<int> void any_cast();  // so dumb
```

and then

```
    any a = 42;
    printf("%d\n", any_cast<int>(a));
```

and it would Just Work. (The ["so dumb" part](https://wandbox.org/permlink/9BPFMEib83VJby6Z) is [because C++ is stupid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIJziqkSaBk).)

So, IMO you should stop calling them `static_any_cast` and `bad_static_any_cast` and start calling them `any_cast` and `bad_any_cast`. In fact, I would strongly suggest that you should just use the standard `std::bad_any_cast` exception type instead of making up your own... at least, if you're in an environment where the standard one can be assumed (or detected) to exist.

---

Nit: Your default `size_t Align = 8` could productively be replaced with `size_t Align = alignof(std::aligned_storage_t<Size>)`. This prevents you from quietly overaligning the buffer of a `static_any<4>`.

---

I'm sure there's more, but this is enough for one review. :)